# Is possible to change Desktop/Documents/Pictures directory location with commands on a batch file or powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

I already read these two posts:

[Change location 1](https://superuser.com/questions/328763/can-you-change-the-location-of-the-desktop-folder-in-windows)

[Change location 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1295464/can-i-move-the-default-documents-folders-location-in-windows-10-using-powershell)

I need to do this manually on a couple of computers, not via GPO and MKLINK is not a valid option. But since I need to move the Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos directories I will like to do it via script either batch file or powershell. Is that possible?

Regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like the answer in your first link that describes the registry change would work for you, either as a batch file or Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You mean something like this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709398/set-location-of-special-folders-with-powershell)

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Sets a known folder's path using SHSetKnownFolderPath.
.PARAMETER Folder
    The known folder whose path to set.
.PARAMETER Path
    The path.
#>
function Set-KnownFolderPath {
    Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [ValidateSet('AddNewPrograms', 'AdminTools', 'AppUpdates', 'CDBurning', 'ChangeRemovePrograms', 'CommonAdminTools', 'CommonOEMLinks', 'CommonPrograms', 'CommonStartMenu', 'CommonStartup', 'CommonTemplates', 'ComputerFolder', 'ConflictFolder', 'ConnectionsFolder', 'Contacts', 'ControlPanelFolder', 'Cookies', 'Desktop', 'Documents', 'Downloads', 'Favorites', 'Fonts', 'Games', 'GameTasks', 'History', 'InternetCache', 'InternetFolder', 'Links', 'LocalAppData', 'LocalAppDataLow', 'LocalizedResourcesDir', 'Music', 'NetHood', 'NetworkFolder', 'OriginalImages', 'PhotoAlbums', 'Pictures', 'Playlists', 'PrintersFolder', 'PrintHood', 'Profile', 'ProgramData', 'ProgramFiles', 'ProgramFilesX64', 'ProgramFilesX86', 'ProgramFilesCommon', 'ProgramFilesCommonX64', 'ProgramFilesCommonX86', 'Programs', 'Public', 'PublicDesktop', 'PublicDocuments', 'PublicDownloads', 'PublicGameTasks', 'PublicMusic', 'PublicPictures', 'PublicVideos', 'QuickLaunch', 'Recent', 'RecycleBinFolder', 'ResourceDir', 'RoamingAppData', 'SampleMusic', 'SamplePictures', 'SamplePlaylists', 'SampleVideos', 'SavedGames', 'SavedSearches', 'SEARCH_CSC', 'SEARCH_MAPI', 'SearchHome', 'SendTo', 'SidebarDefaultParts', 'SidebarParts', 'StartMenu', 'Startup', 'SyncManagerFolder', 'SyncResultsFolder', 'SyncSetupFolder', 'System', 'SystemX86', 'Templates', 'TreeProperties', 'UserProfiles', 'UsersFiles', 'Videos', 'Windows')]
            [string]$KnownFolder,

            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$Path
    )

    # Define known folder GUIDs
    $KnownFolders = @{
        'AddNewPrograms' = 'de61d971-5ebc-4f02-a3a9-6c82895e5c04';
        'AdminTools' = '724EF170-A42D-4FEF-9F26-B60E846FBA4F';
        'AppUpdates' = 'a305ce99-f527-492b-8b1a-7e76fa98d6e4';
        'CDBurning' = '9E52AB10-F80D-49DF-ACB8-4330F5687855';
        'ChangeRemovePrograms' = 'df7266ac-9274-4867-8d55-3bd661de872d';
        'CommonAdminTools' = 'D0384E7D-BAC3-4797-8F14-CBA229B392B5';
        'CommonOEMLinks' = 'C1BAE2D0-10DF-4334-BEDD-7AA20B227A9D';
        'CommonPrograms' = '0139D44E-6AFE-49F2-8690-3DAFCAE6FFB8';
        'CommonStartMenu' = 'A4115719-D62E-491D-AA7C-E74B8BE3B067';
        'CommonStartup' = '82A5EA35-D9CD-47C5-9629-E15D2F714E6E';
        'CommonTemplates' = 'B94237E7-57AC-4347-9151-B08C6C32D1F7';
        'ComputerFolder' = '0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7';
        'ConflictFolder' = '4bfefb45-347d-4006-a5be-ac0cb0567192';
        'ConnectionsFolder' = '6F0CD92B-2E97-45D1-88FF-B0D186B8DEDD';
        'Contacts' = '56784854-C6CB-462b-8169-88E350ACB882';
        'ControlPanelFolder' = '82A74AEB-AEB4-465C-A014-D097EE346D63';
        'Cookies' = '2B0F765D-C0E9-4171-908E-08A611B84FF6';
        'Desktop' = 'B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641';
        'Documents' = 'FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7';
        'Downloads' = '374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B';
        'Favorites' = '1777F761-68AD-4D8A-87BD-30B759FA33DD';
        'Fonts' = 'FD228CB7-AE11-4AE3-864C-16F3910AB8FE';
        'Games' = 'CAC52C1A-B53D-4edc-92D7-6B2E8AC19434';
        'GameTasks' = '054FAE61-4DD8-4787-80B6-090220C4B700';
        'History' = 'D9DC8A3B-B784-432E-A781-5A1130A75963';
        'InternetCache' = '352481E8-33BE-4251-BA85-6007CAEDCF9D';
        'InternetFolder' = '4D9F7874-4E0C-4904-967B-40B0D20C3E4B';
        'Links' = 'bfb9d5e0-c6a9-404c-b2b2-ae6db6af4968';
        'LocalAppData' = 'F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091';
        'LocalAppDataLow' = 'A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16';
        'LocalizedResourcesDir' = '2A00375E-224C-49DE-B8D1-440DF7EF3DDC';
        'Music' = '4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43';
        'NetHood' = 'C5ABBF53-E17F-4121-8900-86626FC2C973';
        'NetworkFolder' = 'D20BEEC4-5CA8-4905-AE3B-BF251EA09B53';
        'OriginalImages' = '2C36C0AA-5812-4b87-BFD0-4CD0DFB19B39';
        'PhotoAlbums' = '69D2CF90-FC33-4FB7-9A0C-EBB0F0FCB43C';
        'Pictures' = '33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB';
        'Playlists' = 'DE92C1C7-837F-4F69-A3BB-86E631204A23';
        'PrintersFolder' = '76FC4E2D-D6AD-4519-A663-37BD56068185';
        'PrintHood' = '9274BD8D-CFD1-41C3-B35E-B13F55A758F4';
        'Profile' = '5E6C858F-0E22-4760-9AFE-EA3317B67173';
        'ProgramData' = '62AB5D82-FDC1-4DC3-A9DD-070D1D495D97';
        'ProgramFiles' = '905e63b6-c1bf-494e-b29c-65b732d3d21a';
        'ProgramFilesX64' = '6D809377-6AF0-444b-8957-A3773F02200E';
        'ProgramFilesX86' = '7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E';
        'ProgramFilesCommon' = 'F7F1ED05-9F6D-47A2-AAAE-29D317C6F066';
        'ProgramFilesCommonX64' = '6365D5A7-0F0D-45E5-87F6-0DA56B6A4F7D';
        'ProgramFilesCommonX86' = 'DE974D24-D9C6-4D3E-BF91-F4455120B917';
        'Programs' = 'A77F5D77-2E2B-44C3-A6A2-ABA601054A51';
        'Public' = 'DFDF76A2-C82A-4D63-906A-5644AC457385';
        'PublicDesktop' = 'C4AA340D-F20F-4863-AFEF-F87EF2E6BA25';
        'PublicDocuments' = 'ED4824AF-DCE4-45A8-81E2-FC7965083634';
        'PublicDownloads' = '3D644C9B-1FB8-4f30-9B45-F670235F79C0';
        'PublicGameTasks' = 'DEBF2536-E1A8-4c59-B6A2-414586476AEA';
        'PublicMusic' = '3214FAB5-9757-4298-BB61-92A9DEAA44FF';
        'PublicPictures' = 'B6EBFB86-6907-413C-9AF7-4FC2ABF07CC5';
        'PublicVideos' = '2400183A-6185-49FB-A2D8-4A392A602BA3';
        'QuickLaunch' = '52a4f021-7b75-48a9-9f6b-4b87a210bc8f';
        'Recent' = 'AE50C081-EBD2-438A-8655-8A092E34987A';
        'RecycleBinFolder' = 'B7534046-3ECB-4C18-BE4E-64CD4CB7D6AC';
        'ResourceDir' = '8AD10C31-2ADB-4296-A8F7-E4701232C972';
        'RoamingAppData' = '3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D';
        'SampleMusic' = 'B250C668-F57D-4EE1-A63C-290EE7D1AA1F';
        'SamplePictures' = 'C4900540-2379-4C75-844B-64E6FAF8716B';
        'SamplePlaylists' = '15CA69B3-30EE-49C1-ACE1-6B5EC372AFB5';
        'SampleVideos' = '859EAD94-2E85-48AD-A71A-0969CB56A6CD';
        'SavedGames' = '4C5C32FF-BB9D-43b0-B5B4-2D72E54EAAA4';
        'SavedSearches' = '7d1d3a04-debb-4115-95cf-2f29da2920da';
        'SEARCH_CSC' = 'ee32e446-31ca-4aba-814f-a5ebd2fd6d5e';
        'SEARCH_MAPI' = '98ec0e18-2098-4d44-8644-66979315a281';
        'SearchHome' = '190337d1-b8ca-4121-a639-6d472d16972a';
        'SendTo' = '8983036C-27C0-404B-8F08-102D10DCFD74';
        'SidebarDefaultParts' = '7B396E54-9EC5-4300-BE0A-2482EBAE1A26';
        'SidebarParts' = 'A75D362E-50FC-4fb7-AC2C-A8BEAA314493';
        'StartMenu' = '625B53C3-AB48-4EC1-BA1F-A1EF4146FC19';
        'Startup' = 'B97D20BB-F46A-4C97-BA10-5E3608430854';
        'SyncManagerFolder' = '43668BF8-C14E-49B2-97C9-747784D784B7';
        'SyncResultsFolder' = '289a9a43-be44-4057-a41b-587a76d7e7f9';
        'SyncSetupFolder' = '0F214138-B1D3-4a90-BBA9-27CBC0C5389A';
        'System' = '1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7';
        'SystemX86' = 'D65231B0-B2F1-4857-A4CE-A8E7C6EA7D27';
        'Templates' = 'A63293E8-664E-48DB-A079-DF759E0509F7';
        'TreeProperties' = '5b3749ad-b49f-49c1-83eb-15370fbd4882';
        'UserProfiles' = '0762D272-C50A-4BB0-A382-697DCD729B80';
        'UsersFiles' = 'f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f';
        'Videos' = '18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC';
        'Windows' = 'F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23';
    }

    # Define SHSetKnownFolderPath if it hasn't been defined already
    $Type = ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'KnownFolders').Type
    if (-not $Type) {
        $Signature = @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public extern static int SHSetKnownFolderPath(ref Guid folderId, uint flags, IntPtr token, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string path);
'@
        $Type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 'KnownFolders' -Namespace 'SHSetKnownFolderPath' -PassThru
    }

    # Validate the path
    if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
        # Call SHSetKnownFolderPath
        return $Type::SHSetKnownFolderPath([ref]$KnownFolders[$KnownFolder], 0, 0, $Path)
    } else {
        throw New-Object System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException "Could not find part of the path $Path."
    }
}

Set-KnownFolderPath -KnownFolder 'Desktop' -Path 'C:\'
```

Answer (score 2):

A small batch to **show** currently used folders

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\14\SU_1414043.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Spc=                                         "
set "key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

for /f "tokens=*" %%K in ('Reg query "%key%" ') Do (
    set "Line=%%K"
    For /F "tokens=1-2* delims=|" %%A in ("!Line:    =|!") do if "%%C" neq "" (
        Set "Val="%%A"%Spc%"
        Echo !Val:~0,40! = "%%C"
    )
)
```

Sample output (all of type REG_EXPAND_SZ) :

```
"AppData"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming"
"Cache"                                  = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache"
"Cookies"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"
"Desktop"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
"Favorites"                              = "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites"
"History"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History"
"Local AppData"                          = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local"
"My Music"                               = "%USERPROFILE%\Music"
"My Pictures"                            = "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures"
"My Video"                               = "%USERPROFILE%\Videos"
"NetHood"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts"
"Personal"                               = "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
"PrintHood"                              = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts"
"Programs"                               = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
"Recent"                                 = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
"SendTo"                                 = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo"
"Start Menu"                             = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
"Startup"                                = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
"Templates"                              = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates"
"{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" = "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
"{24D89E24-2F19-4534-9DDE-6A6671FBB8FE}" = "C:\Users\LotPings\OneDrive\Dokumente"
"{339719B5-8C47-4894-94C2-D8F77ADD44A6}" = "C:\Users\LotPings\OneDrive\Bilder"
"{767E6811-49CB-4273-87C2-20F355E1085B}" = "C:\Users\LotPings\OneDrive\Bilder\Eigene Aufnahmen"
```

To also expand `%USERPROFILE%` prepend the Echo line with `call`:

```
        call Echo !Val:~0,40! = "%%C"
```

Similarly you can change values with (folders should exist with appropriate rights):

```
@Echo off
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
set "Typ=REG_EXPAND_SZ"
set "Val=My Video"
set "Dat=D:\Videos"
Reg Add "%Key%" /V "%Val% /T %Typ% /D "%Dat%" /f
```

Use on your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:

```
$Dest = 'C:\USers\Keith\Sandbox\USFRedirect'
$USF = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'

@"
Folder,USFvalue
Documents,Personal#{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}
Pictures,My Pictures#{0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639}
Music,My Music#{a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d}
Videos,My Video#{35286a68-3c57-41a1-bbb1-0eae73d76c95}
Downloads,{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}#{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}
3D Objects,{31C0DD25-9439-4F12-BF41-7FF4EDA38722}
Desktop,Desktop
"@ | ConvertFrom-csv |
   %{
     $NewPath = "$Dest\$($_.Folder)"
     If (!(test-path $NewPath)) {
        new-item -Path ([Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($NewPath)) -ItemType Directory -force | out-null
     }#If()

     $_.USFValue.split('#') |
        %{
          New-ItemProperty -Path $USF -Name $_ -value $NewPath -PropertyType 'ExpandString' -force | Out-Null
        }# Inner ForEach
   }# Outer ForEach
```

Keith

Comment: I focused on the registry values, but adding a 'move-item' for the folder would be trivial.

Comment: Why not define `$NewPath = Join-Path $Dest $_.Folder` first and then `Test-Path` instead of 3 times combining `"$Dest\$($_.Folder)"`. You should also provide a way to [undo your changes](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/).

Comment: @LotPings: Short answer: I was focused on the core logic and trying to get to bed :D. Undoing the changes is as simple as 
$Dest = '%USERPROFILE%'
 and running the script again. The suggestion to define 'NewPath' earlier is a good one & I'll edit the code accordingly (though I still prefer an expansion string for readability).